# Ubuntu 20.04 fprint update

Tags: ubuntu, updates

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and wanted to update it. After restart of a system software update popped up and stated that software update is available. I saw that it suggests to update fprint in a very long list of available updates. Is it included in main repository? I do not want to install anything from universe.
I did not change anything just installed Ubuntu and restarted the computer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I cannot find anything definitive on this. fprint is not installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 system and it is updating properly. Did you install an App that requires fprint? That is all I can think of

Comment: I did install the Ubunru 20.04 LTS and did not change anything. After restart of the system I got a notification that updates are available. In the update list I see fprint.

Answer (score 0):

You have found the
[Fingerprint reader support](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/) :

> The fprint project aims to add support for consumer fingerprint reader
> devices, in Linux, as well as other free Unices.
>
> Previously, Linux support for such devices has been scattered amongst
> different projects (many incomplete) and inconsistent in that
> application developers would have to implement support for each type
> of fingerprint reader separately. For more information on where we
> came from, see the project history page.
>
> We’re trying to change that by providing a central system to support
> all the fingerprint readers we can get our hands on. The software is
> free software and in the long term we’re shooting for adoption by
> distributions, integration into common desktop environments, etc.

For programmers, this unfortunate name may cause a confusion with the
`fprint` C-function.

Comment: Is it included in main repository for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Your experience indicates that it's included.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).